# Test if get_user_meta is false or not present

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce

I have a checkbox in my template to enable ( checked ) or disable ( unchecked ) the shipping options.

My intention is to display a `div` with some information only if the checkbox is unchecked - shipping disabled.

I am trying to insert into my template and work with the following If statement:

```
<!-- Show DIV if checkbox is unchecked - false -->
<?php if( get_user_meta( $post->post_author, '_shipping_checkbox', false ) == 'yes' ) { ?>  
        <div id="info">
                  <p>Shipping is currently disabled</p>    
        </div>   
<?php } ?>
```

But that doesn't seem to work and the DIV is not showing up.

If I try and test it with `TRUE` instead of false, so if I check the checkbox and change the statement to `true`

```
<?php if( get_user_meta( $post->post_author, '_shipping_checkbox', true ) == 'yes' ) { ?>
```

Then the div is now showing up correctly.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Or should I be doing this different way ?

I am trying to avoid Jquery and Javascript, I just don't know how to work with scripts correctly.

Comment: check this value $post->post_author

Comment: so what's wrong with the value? It works ok with true, why not false?

Comment: Could I encourage you to edit your title for something more specific? I really hate the generic phrase "it's not working". :) Also, see below for my suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code that I can see.

1. You aren't testing if the user meta is false. Your condition is testing if the user meta equals `"yes"`.
2. the third parameter of [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) is a boolean that  if true returns the value of meta data field, if false returns an array.

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
<!-- Show DIV if checkbox is unchecked - false -->
<?php if( get_user_meta( $post->post_author, '_shipping_checkbox', true) !== 'yes' ) { ?>  
        <div id="info">
                  <p>Shipping is currently disabled</p>    
        </div>   
<?php } ?>
```

If the meta was checked and saved as "yes" (WooCommerce does all of its booleans as "yes"/"no". Then you can infer that if the value *does not equal* yes, that the shipping is disabled.